# My for statement isn't working properly

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have tried so much different iterations of the for loops and all of them dont work properly or work only halfway. So I cant figure it out.
Heres my form:

[image]

So what its supposed to do is create a folder for each node in the treeview (Named FolderTV) when I click the Create folders button.
What it currently does is only creates the New_Mod folder and the Data folder nothing else. I want it to create a folder for every node and subnode. For example it would create the New_Mod folder and then within that folder It will create the Data, Models, and Textures folder and within the Data folder it would create a Scripts folder.

Here's my code for that button:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= FoldersTV.Nodes.Count; i++)
        {

            FoldersTV.SelectedNode = FoldersTV.TopNode;
            MessageBox.Show("Current Node: " + FoldersTV.SelectedNode.Text.ToString());
            Directory.CreateDirectory(SEAppdata + "\\" + FoldersTV.SelectedNode.Text.ToString());
            for (int x = 0; x <= FoldersTV.Nodes.Count; x++)
            {
                TreeNode nextNode = FoldersTV.SelectedNode.NextVisibleNode;
                MessageBox.Show("Next Node: " + nextNode.Text.ToString());
                Directory.CreateDirectory(SEAppdata + "\\" + FoldersTV.SelectedNode.Text.ToString() + "\\" + nextNode.Text.ToString());
                x++;
            }
            i++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: "What it currently does is only creates the New_Mod folder and the Data folder nothing else." were you able to investigate the cause for this? is there an exception?

Comment: For a start, you're calling x++ and i++ twice. Once in the for itself, and once in the body.

Comment: Why don't you use `foreach`, which would be way more convenient?

Comment: I cannot see any `FolderTV.Nodes[i]`. You are accessing `TopNode` and `NextVisibleNode` only.

Comment: When I run the program it doesn't show any errors it runs but only creates the New_Mod and Data folder

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair I don't know how to use the for each loop.

Comment: Do `foreach(TreeNode node in FoldersTV.Nodes)` with inner `foreach(TreeNode second in node.Nodes)`.

Comment: @firda I did your for loop and its almost working. The only folder that isnt being crated is the Scripts folder.  This is a link to the current for loop I have https://docs.google.com/document/d/10zalxhyyQeO-HmfaMVASrVWA1VLv-pWUr_Nuu37NOdA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Scripts are in third level. Either add another `foreach` or make it recursive (which is better, will handle any structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (untested) recursive solution and try to understand it first ;)

```
private void CreateDirs(string path, IEnumerable<TreeNode> nodes) {
    foreach(var node in nodes) {
    //  string dir = path + "\\" + node.Text;
        string dir = Path.Combine(path, node.Text);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        CreateDirs(dir, node.Nodes);
    }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    CreateDirs(SEAppdata, FoldersTV.Nodes);
}
```

**EDIT:** Version with few debug printouts:

```
// using System.Diagnostics;
private void CreateDirs(string path, IEnumerable<TreeNode> nodes) {

//  iterate through each node (use the variable `node`!)
    foreach(var node in nodes) {
    //  combine the path with node.Text
        string dir = Path.Combine(path, node.Text);

    //  create the directory + debug printout
        Debug.WriteLine("CreateDirectory({0})", dir);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

    //  recursion (create sub-dirs for all sub-nodes)
        CreateDirs(dir, node.Nodes);
    }
}
```

**See:** [`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: please do not use `path + "\\" + node.Text` - rather go for `Path.Combine`!

Comment: @DarkWolfModding why does it not seem to work, what is the expected vs actual outcome? is there an exception? please be more specific with your description!

Comment: Its supposed to create the Scripts folder as well as all the other nodes as folders. But both the suggested solutions wont create the scripts folder it just creates the others. The scripts folder is supposed to be inside the Data folder its not getting created though. And both solutions don't produce errors.

Comment: Try to print every `dir` to output window. It has to work, there is no way to make it create Data and not Scripts, it is recursive. It either creates all of them or none.

Comment: @DarkWolfModding have you debugged the stack? can you isolate the faulting line?

Comment: @firda suggesting adding logging is perfect! this involves the OP a bit in bug-hunting ;)

Comment: This is the code I used to create the scripts folder when the check box is checked. FoldersTV.SelectedNode.NextVisibleNode.Nodes.Add("Scripts");

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I use F5 (Debug Mode) in visual studio 2013 and i test each button and nothing pops in the call stack tab. Nothing pops into any of those little windows for debugging

Comment: Learn how to use [`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z9k5ydz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and similar (especially [`Assert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e63efys0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: I have uploaded the current version of the C# project. If any of you want to look at the whole project. Its here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Dsnll8WvTRQjAta1VQWklqZ0E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @DarkWolfModding Additionally you should learn what the Debugger does and how it works. Those little windows only give you some content when you pause the execution. You could eg set a breakpoint to the `string dir = ....`-line and inspect the creation with F10 (or sth alike)...

Comment: @DarkWolfModding and please put some minimal effort into solving the problem yourself. There are numerous hints floating around and your pretended disinterest could turn people off - the tenor should not be like "you guy, solve my problem" rather "could you possibly guide me to the solution?"

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Im trying to figure it out but im fairly new to C#

Comment: I got it working to generate the scripts folder in the right place but I need to figure out how to generate a directory that the nodes are a child of another child node with a limit of lets say 5 child nodes (User can only have up to 5 child nodes per parent node).  Here's the semi working code where it generates (Into a messagebox for debugging) the directory names.   https://docs.google.com/document/d/15cw14VH3LpSO3wAjgJ4dsNCvqL_NbTZtY0Di_V39Mjg/edit?usp=sharing     any tips on how to approach this.

Comment: @DarkWolfModding: You are not using the variables from `foreach`, again. Stop using `SelectedNode` and such, use `node` and `nodeTwo`. Why do you think you iterate through the nodes? To have access to them. Do you think they will be miraculously selected in the tree view? **No, `SelectedNode` is untouched by the `foreach`!** You should first learn the very basics of programming, it seems. Go back to my recursive solution, use `Debug.WriteLine` (instead of MessageBox) and understand how it works.